# MVC .NET Model Binding to Array on the fly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

In Scotts blog [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) he describes how to post an array of objects to the controller.

**My Question**  how best to generate a View for this that allows the user to add more array items on the fly?

If I write

```
 foreach(MyModel item in Model)
 {
     <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.Name)</p>
 }
```

and have the controller add a new item to the array each time it generates  `<input type="text" name="item.Name" />`  missing the [1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) Array index.

If I hand code the `<input>` then it works but I lose all the client side validation attributes like `data-val-required="Name is required"`

What I want to be able to do is have the User add new Items to the array on the fly and still retain unobtrusive validation?. What's the best practice for this?

I am thinking I have write it myself using jQuery but if so can I keep the validation?

**Update**
Seems like Tassadaque answer is a nice .NET solution but looks like a lot of server side code to do something which should be very easy.
Muhammad Adeel Zahi answer is ok but still misses out client side validation.

I think I will end up just writing my own client side  HTML manually and using jQuery live and validation plug-in. So I can do all my own validation and adding and removing of new Items all client side without any calls to the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may see [This](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/validating-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style) In this post steve Validated a variable length list in which textboxes may be added or deleted dynamically

Answer (score 1):

When rendering and binding to lists or arrays, I normally prefer for loop over foreach loop because it will generate required indices for the modelbinder to bind data to the model.

```
for(int i=0;i<Model.Count(); i++)
{
   <%:Html.TextBox("Items["+i+"].Name", Model[i].Name)%>
}
```

I'm not comfortable with strongly typed helpers when it comes to list binding but its purely a matter of personal preference. However, if you are allowing the user to dynamically add and remove items from page through JavaScript you have to take care of indices yourself.

### Edit

I have [blogged](http://zahidadeel.blogspot.com/2011/05/master-detail-form-in-aspnet-mvc-3-i.html) about creating master detail form in asp.net mvc using jQuery templates which is relevant in list binding scenario as well.

Comment: Thanks this helps generte the inputs but it still does not put the data-val-required="Name is required" attibutes on the form