# Passing list from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, arraylist

I want to pass an ArrayList of Object from ARCCreate so the items can be added to the database as multiple entries, these are my codes:

My Model :

```
public class M_ARC : DbContext
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Periode")]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("[2][0]([1][4-9]|[2-9][0-9])(0[1-9]|1[012])", ErrorMessage = "Format tidak sesuai. Contoh format : 201407 (Juli 2014)")]
    public int Periode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email SPDT")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EmailSPDT { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Jatuh Tempo")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime JatuhTempoDT { get; set; }

}
```

My View :

```
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.Label("Agustus")
    </th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="EmailSPDT" class="pengirimanDT" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="JatuhTempoDT" class="tanggapanDT" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="InformasiBankDT" class="informasiBankDT" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.Label("September")
    </th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="EmailSPDT" class="pengirimanDT" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="JatuhTempoDT" class="tanggapanDT" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="InformasiBankDT" class="informasiBankDT" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.Label("Oktober")
    </th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="EmailSPDT" class="pengirimanDT" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="JatuhTempoDT" class="tanggapanDT" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="InformasiBankDT" class="informasiBankDT" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

And my Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ARCCreate(List<M_ARC> ARCList)
{
    foreach (M_ARC item in ARCList)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Arcs.Add(item);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else return View();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ARCIndex");
}
```

Is this a proper way for inserting multiple entries ? or Is there better solution for inserting multiple entries into my database?

Comment: Just want to clarify, you are using Entity Framework right?

Comment: yes you are doing correctly...

Comment: @DrSchizo..yes.he is using entity...

Comment: Why is your M_ARC entity inheriting DbContext? And you shouldn't be passing the database entity to the View. Your should NEVER use a database entity in your view model.

Comment: @DrSchizo Yes I am using Entity Framework. But i am still confused in adding and passing the entities from view to controller. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Ideally you want to separate your domain models from your entity so essentially directly exposing how your database looks like in the view is generally bad practice. Also, not sure whether you need to call db.SaveChanges() every time, just do it outside the loop? One commit as opposed to several.

Comment: You are also a bit confused about something else - there is no `ArrayList` in the code you posted, just a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have some misunderstandings about MVC and EF. You might want to read up a bit more on the two concepts.

First, your "model" is called `M_ARC` and inherits from `DbContext`. The class inheriting from `DbContext` should not be the model but provide a property to retrieve/update the model from/to the database.

Second, you cannot pass data from the view to the controller. It is the other way around. What happens when the user clicks a button is, the form fields are posted to the server and handled by the controller. I reckon what you try to achieve is rendering the view such that the form fields will have the correct names to be mapped into an array. This is not a new question though, you can find some help here: [MVC .NET Model Binding to Array on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496593/mvc-net-model-binding-to-array-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you want to submit multiple entries where each entry contains these properties: `Periode`, `EmailSPDT`, `JatuhTempoDT`, and `InformasiBankDT`. Here's how you should create your model class

```
public class ARCCreateModel
{
    public ARCCreateModel()
    {
        this.Details = new List<ARCCreateDetail>();
    }

    public List<ARCCreateDetail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class ARCCreateDetail
{
    [Display(Name = "Periode")]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("[2][0]([1][4-9]|[2-9][0-9])(0[1-9]|1[012])", ErrorMessage = "Format tidak sesuai. Contoh format : 201407 (Juli 2014)")]
    public int Periode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email SPDT")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EmailSPDT { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Jatuh Tempo")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime JatuhTempoDT { get; set; }

}
```

Then pass an instance of `ARCCreateModel` to the view in the controller get method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ARCCreate()
{
    ARCCreateModel model = new ARCCreateModel();

    // generate the multiple entries
    ARCCreateDetail detail1 = new ARCCreateDetail();
    detail1.Periode = 201408;
    model.Details.Add(detail1);

    // add more details if necessary
    ARCCreateDetail detail2 = new ARCCreateDetail();
    detail2.Periode = 201409;
    model.Details.Add(detail2);

    return View(model);
}
```

Your view should be like this based on the definition of `ARCCreateModel` above

```
@model ARCCreateModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Details.Count; i++)
        {
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Model.Details[i].Periode
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Details[@i].EmailSPDT" class="pengirimanDT" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Details[@i].JatuhTempoDT" class="tanggapanDT" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Details[@i].InformasiBankDT" class="informasiBankDT" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

and finally when you submit the form, you can get the multiple entries in `model.Details` as below

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ARCCreate(ARCCreateModel model)
{
    foreach (ARCCreateDetail item in model.Details)
    {
        // get the entered values and save to database here
        // assuming there's Arc table with properties similar to ARCCreateDetail
        Arc arc = new Arc();
        arc.Periode = item.Periode;
        arc.EmailSPDT = item.EmailSPDT;
        arc.JatuhTempoDT = item.JatuhTempoDT;
        arc.InformasiBankDT = item.InformasiBankDT;

        db.Arcs.Add(arc);
    }

    // submit the changes to EF
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("ARCIndex");
}
```

Please note that the key is how you set the name attribute of the textboxes for each entry, i.e `Details[0].EmailSPDT` or `Details[1].JatuhTempoDT` so the entered values will be in the exact same order as in `model.Details` property.